# Using a custom culture in Azure web sites

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an app we've developed that will be translated to tagalog. No big deal, I thought. We've done translation dozens of times. However, apparently this culture is not supported by default.  So I looked and found CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder, but that requires admin privileges, something my azure web site most definitely will not have.

Is there a way to use a custom culture without registering it, or alternatively, register a custom culture on a reserved Azure web site instance?

I find it absolutely mind boggling that I might have to use something other than Azure Websites simply because of the lack of forethought and design surrounding globalization.

Comment: Why not just implement the culture as an `IFormatProvider` that you use whenever you need a culture?

Comment: Because that won't work with things like localized data annotations (validation attributes), resource managers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old but I did end up finding an alternative.

https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n

It sits outside your app as an IHttpModule that intercepts responses and does localization by replacing screens with a specific delimiter ([[[ and ]]] respectively, by default). It uses gettext/po standards and IMHO, is everything ASP.NET localization *should* have been from the beginning.